# Input of double is improper eventhoug converter is

Tags: c, function

I've been struggling with the following program that helps me cheat in my maths class calculating the quadratic equation:

```
/*Improved version of my maths cheat code -w-,
this program has the same functionality as the last but with
cleaner and more correct code. Notes taken from the post made in
codereview.stackechange to make it less of a dumpster fire.
The program is not functional already.*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double a,b,c,d;

//Get values of the equation
void get_values (void){
        printf("Dame el valor de a: ");
        scanf("%g", &a);
        printf("Dame el valor de b: ");
        scanf("%g", &b);
        printf("Dame el valor de c: ");
        scanf("%g", &c);
        }

//Calculates the discriminante
double discriminante (double a, double b, double c){
        double result;
        result = b*b-4*a*c;
        return result;
                }

//Prints the result of the equation based on the square root
//of the discriminate
void display (double d){
        if (d>0){
                printf("El resultado es: (%g±%g)/%g\n", -b, sqrt(d), a*2);
                }
        else if (d<0){
                printf("El resultado es: (%g±%gi)/%g\n", -b, sqrt(-d), a*2);
                }
        else { // d == 0
                printf("El resultado es: %g/%g\n", b, a*2);
                }
}

int main(){
        get_values();
        d = discriminante(a,b,c);
        printf("El valor del discriminante es: %g\n",d);
        display(d);
        return 0;
        }
```

I made a post in codereview.stackexchange to get some feedback on my code. After rewritting the thing in a cleaner generally better way, I found the small issue that the functions never take the input properly. I've checked the `scanf` and converters for an hour now, and I'm just baffled at this point on why it just refuses to take input properly. Did I use an improper converter or did I made an error at `discriminante`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%g` in `scanf()` is for reading `float`. You should use `%lg` to read `double`.

Note that using `%g` in `printf()` to print `double` is fine.

Comment: Oh, I missed it because my book lists `%ld` as the converter for `long int`, thanks.